# how to use mapreduce when key is not in the first line : Hadoop Mapreduce

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

Can any one quide me how to solve the below using MapReduce in hadoop .

Lets say i have a file with the below structure

- Record 1 - value1
- Record 2 - value2
- Record 3 - value3
- Record 4 -value4
- Record 5 - value5
- Record 6 - value6
- Record 7 - key1
- Record 8 – value8
- Record 9 – value9
- Record 10 – value10
- Record 11 – value11
- Record 12 – value12
- Record 13 – value13
- Record 14 – key2

I want the output to be a concatenated string of key and value as below
output

- Key1Value1 Value2 Value3 Value4 Value5 Value6
- Key2 Value8 Value9Value10 Value11 Value12 Value13

Comment: It's not clear...You mean you want to get all record from 1-7 in one place

Comment: sorry if i miss lead you. I have restructured the question.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can solve the problem in many ways depending on the structure and size of your data and files, maybe with a bit more of info we could give you a more accurate answer:

1. Using the **CombineFileInputFormat** class if you have the same fields within the same file.
2. Preventing splitting subclassing **FileInputFormat** and overriding **isSplittable()** method.

You could also check the class **KeyValueTextInputFormat** that allows you to read files line by line using something different than the line offset as the key. You can specify the separator (the comma) via the **mapreduce.input.keyvaluelinerecordreader.key.value.separator**

I hope it helped

Comment: Thanks, i am pretty new to this i believe i need to read more on the information that you have provided. Thanks again for your help. Just i case if you havent noticed i have restructured the question.